# how to close request session

Tags: python-3.x, request

I have this recursive function which finds all hrefs links and then each link finds links (recursive):

```
def getLinks(pageUrl):
    try:        
        html = requests.get(enlance, verify=False)      
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)        
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser", from_encoding="iso-8859-1") 
    for link in bsObj.find_all("a", href=re.compile("^(/)")):

        page = link.get('href')     
        pages.add(page)

        getLinks(page)

    getLinks("")
```

The problem with this is that the ram memory consumes so fast.

How can I solve this memory consumption?

Comment: Don't use recursion?

Comment: but i need to find all links after one link is found, i want to scrap all links inside the website, and not just the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of this might help:

```
visited_links = []
unvisited_links = [pageURL]
while (unvisited_links) > 0:
    link = unvisited_links.pop()
    if link not in visited_links:
        visited_links.push(link)
        for each new_link in page at link: # pseudocode
            if new_link not in visited_links:
                unvisited_links.push(new_link)
#At this point, visited_links has your list of links
```

This not only avoids overhead introduced by recursion, but avoids re-visiting links (which is probably slower than doing the checking; certainly more memory-wasting).

Comment: doing that only scraps the first web, and i would like to scrap from all emails in the entire website

Comment: No, it adds all the links from the first page, then all links it finds on the page each of those links to, etc.  Emails?

Comment: but visited_links will always be empty or am i wrong?

Comment: Was before edit; different problem than not covering whole site